# Unable to install packages after updating Raspberry pi

Tags: raspbian, software-installation, update, packages

I recently updated rpi firmware to 3.12.30+ by running
sudo rpi-update

However after this update, i am unable to install new packages on my pi. On trying to install ristretto, links2, pqiv, fim packages i get the following error 
"Unable to detect package"

On trying to install fbi, i get the following error
[image: On trying to install fbi]

Have been stuck now. Is this an update issue? 
Should i consider re-installing previous version or is there a way to move back to the previous update?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rpi-update` is a [distro agnostic shell script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Hexxeh/rpi-update/master/rpi-update) (i.e., it could be used the same way on Arch, pidora, etc.) and does not invoke or involve any element of the Debian package management system.

Just updating the firmware and kernel should not affect apt's functionality either, *unless* of course it's fubar'd your internet connection.  That doesn't look like the case here, but it could be, so if you aren't sure, confirm that.

> Should i consider re-installing previous version or is there a way to move back to the previous update?

I think you will be chasing a red herring.  I'm not an authority on apt itself, but you will probably get more definitive help on the [U&L Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions).  Leave out the part about `rpi-update` and cite the error message, explaining that `fbi`, etc., should be in the raspbian repo and ask what might have happened to cause this problem.